# Verifying if string S is equal to string T backwards

Tags: c, arrays, string

For example, if I first enter `testing` and then that same word backwards, which is `gnitset`, it should print that the statement is true. I'm not sure what's wrong with my program since I just started with the *strrev* function and strings in general.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char wordS[101], wordT[101];

   scanf("%s", wordS);
   scanf("%s", wordT);

  if (wordS == strrev(wordT)){
    printf("true");
}   
  else printf("false");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problems is comparing pointers, rather than what the pointers point at.   Also `strrev()` - contrary to some claims made by vendors who supply it - is not part of standard C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wordS == strrev(wordT)` compares pointers but not the string.
Use `strcmp` instead.

```
if (strcmp (wordS ,strrev(wordT)) == 0)
```

Comment: or better yet, `strncmp()`  -- good to get in the habit of thinking about boundary checking early on ...

Comment: Thanks. I'm about to look up the difference between those 2 right now.

Comment: `strcmp()` will not run past array bounds if both arguments have a terminating `'\0'`.    The real problem with `strcmp()` comes if a terminating `'\0'` is left off, and `strncmp()` will not always help in that case (e.g. if the upper bound supplied by the caller exceeds the position where the missing terminator should have been).

Comment: @landru27 Disagree about `strncmp()` being better.  A better habit is to use the right tool for the job.  In this case what was needed was a width limit on user input : `scanf("%s"...` --> `scanf("%100s"...`. or `fgets()`.

Comment: @Peter  I see your point; care must be taken in any case; but the way to ensure that, say, some external, user-supplied string data is actually null-terminated is to read it into a buffer that you know is large enough and has been cleared or has one byte left over for an additional non-user-supplied null-terminator; you don't escape the need to know and observe boundaries just by using `strcmp()` (and its cousins); the left hand needs to know what the right hand is doing either way; you can either impose that boundary checking on `strcmp()` ... or use `strncmp()` which won't let you neglect it

Comment: @chux  I agree with you about using the right tool;  I was addressing what is written here in this specific answer;  if I were to address the original code, I would have much more to say; I'd declare a constant and use the same constant to allocate the buffers (+1 for a null-terminator) *and* to limit scanf; etc. ...  I was augmenting Naidu's answer for the OP -- who is "just starting out with strings" by drawing attention to `strncmp()` (and its cousins); I do think it's generally the better choice, but I also agree with you that the solution also has to start at its actual root